# Custom text in MUI Select component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using MUI `Select` in my React application where the user can select one of the option from the list. However, there is a requirement where a user can add a custom text in MUI `Select` to create a new option.

Can anyone help how to achieve the same. Adding custom text in MUI `Select` component.

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible with `Select` but you can do that using `Autocomplete` component. Here is how:

- Take control of the input value and the options
- Detect if the user pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> and add the new option in the `options` list

### Example

```js
const initialOptions = [
  { title: "The Shawshank Redemption" },
  { title: "The Godfather" },
  { title: "The Godfather: Part II" }
];
```

```js
function App() {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState("");
  const [options, setOptions] = React.useState(initialOptions);

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      options={options}
      noOptionsText="Enter to create a new option"
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
      onInputChange={(e, newValue) => {
        setInputValue(newValue);
      }}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          label="Select"
          variant="outlined"
          onKeyDown={(e) => {
            if (
              e.key === "Enter" &&
              options.findIndex((o) => o.title === inputValue) === -1
            ) {
              setOptions((o) => o.concat({ title: inputValue }));
            }
          }}
        />
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 66749678/custom-text-in-mui-select-component]

Comment: hey, i used your example. thanks it worked, but i'm having one issue, if i hit enter it refereshes my page.